# handlebars.js not working in IE9. but IE10, IE Edge, Chrome working

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js, internet-explorer-9

I use my web site to handlebar.js
It it working IE10, IE Edge, Chrome.

But IE 9 version not working.

If connect to IE 9 version, there is no error, but no data is displayed.

I think I declared too much, so I deleted the handlebar area, but no change.
like this

```
var source = $("#entry-template").html(); 
var template = Handlebars.compile(source); 
var html = template(data);
$('body').append(html);
```

There are about 88 lines for used to declare.

What's the problem? please tell me the answer. thanks

Comment: Your above posted code is not enough to get the idea about the issue. I suggest you to post a code sample which can produce the issue with IE 9. I refer sample code from this link. http://jsfiddle.net/aybalasubramanian/N2b5M/1/ I try to run it with IE 9 document mode and it is working fine. Output: https://i.postimg.cc/zBJ8VND6/27.png Also it is recommended to upgrade to IE 11 because IE 9 is outdated not supported currently.

Comment: thanks your comment! I found the right answer. It was because of <Ajax "crossDomain": true>. It works well after it has been delete.

Comment: How to answer to my post? Can you tell me?

Answer (score 0):

I found the right answer. It was because of 
Ajax

```
"crossDomain": true
```

It works well after it has been delete